# Jquery function not firing - onunload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to add a listener to a form so that when the user leaves it, an ajax call is made but nothing seems to be happening.  Don't see any errors in firefox and nothing gets console logged when I leave the page which tells me the code is incorrect.  Fairly new to jquery (and ajax), hoping someone can show me what I'm doing wrong here.

**html: home/folder/index.php**

```
<script>

var rowid = "<?php echo $_SESSION['rowid'] ?>";
var user = "<?php echo $_SESSION['user'] ?>";

</script>
...
<form id="update" method="post" action="index.php?update=1" autocomplete="off">
```

**Jquery: home/scripts/main.js**

```
var end_lock = 0;
$('#update').on('unload', function(){
    end_lock = 1;
    console.log('error');
});
window.onunload = callAjaxRecordLock;
function callAjaxRecordLock(){
    if (end_lock === 1){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'home/includes/ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                method: 'ajax_record_lock',
                rowid: rowid,
                user: user,
                endlock: 1
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**php: home/includes/ajax.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['method'])) {
    $_POST['method']();
}

function ajax_record_lock(){
    $ajax_rowid = $_POST['rowid'];
    $ajax_user = $_POST['user'];
    $ajax_endlock = $_POST['endlock'];

    if (isset($ajax_rowid) && isset($ajax_user) && isset($ajax_endlock)) {
        sp_record_lock($ajax_rowid, $ajax_user, $ajax_endlock);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Found this link https://api.jquery.com/category/events/form-events/ where it appears that beforeunload is not a valid event for a form element. Is there another way to achieve what I need?

Comment: console out at some arbitrary locations on server and jquery to see where it's having a problem. Also try adding callback function to ajax to see if the result reaches back to the client

Comment: added a console log in the $('#update').on('unload', function()...  and nothing got logged.  So I imagine that's where the problem starts.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the AJAX call synchronous. If it’s async, it will never execute because the website will, well, unload. With a synchronous request you lock the browser until its made:

```
async: false
```

However, I think it’s not a good thing to do. Don’t mess with default client behavior, it’s bad user experience.

Comment: This didn't solve my issue but still upvoted since I'm sure this would have gotten me later on.

Comment: You have to bind the unload event to window. Try changing that line to $(window).on(“unload”, function() {